# Loop Matrix to store in Cube

Tags: r

I want to loop an equation through a matrix and store the results in a cube, so that Cube[,,1] is one result of the matrix.

I currently have written the following

```
PercentileReturn <- array(NA, c(RetAge,length(Percentile)+1,nrow(Demo)))
for (i in 1:nrow(Demo)) {
  PercentileReturn[,,i] <-
    PercentileReturn[Demo[i,3]:RetAge,
                     1:length(Percentile),1]<- 
    t(apply((apply(AnnualReturns[(Demo[i,3]):RetAge,],2,cumprod)) *
              Demo[i,4],1,function(x){quantile(x, Percentile, na.rm=T)}))
}
```

and it results in the following error

```
Error in PercentileReturn[, , i] <- PercentileReturn[Demo[i, 3]:RetAge,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I assume it's because the Matrix I am trying to plug in isn't in 3 dimensions.

Basically a stripped down version would be to have an 
array(NA,c(2,2,3)) populated with a matrix times a vector
so that say

```
Matrix  * vector c(1,2,3)
    [,1]    [,2]         
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    4    4
```

would result in the following cube

```
, , 1       
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    4    4

, , 2       
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]    8   8
[2,]    8   8

, , 3       
       [,1] [,2]
[1,]    12  12
[2,]    12  12
```

Answer (score 0):

That will do it:

```
M <- matrix(1:4,2) # in your example M <- matrix(4, 2,2)
x <- 1:3    
array(sapply(x, function(xi) M*xi), c(dim(M), length(x)))
```

Comment: Do you know then How I can relate that to the first section of code? That's where my issue is and is giving me the length error, basically the loop runs on the first vector but then stops

Comment: Sorry, without data it is not reproducable. And for only looking at the code the code is to tricky. Eventually is it a good idea to use a function(M, x) which returns the array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error the first

```
PercentileReturn[,,i]
```

has to also match the dimensions of the loop data below written as

```
PercentileReturn[Demo[i,3]:RetAge,1:length(Percentile),i]
```

Thanks Jogo, I will be using something similar to what you wrote in another issue down the line.